# Masking during Instruction Tuning for LLM finetuning

Tags: natural-language-processing, transformer, large-language-models

I'm currently trying to learn more about LLMs particularly generative decoder only models such as the GPT family of models. I do have one question about masking though.

For me the way masking is performed left-to-right makes sense during pre-training but it is weird to me during instruction fine-tuning when dealing with the input prompt. I therefore have two questions:

- Is the input prompt masked in the same way as the text during pre-training?
- And if so why is it done in this way and have there been studies on it